# C# Array Map/Collect

Tags: c#, ruby, c#-4.0

In Ruby you can use the map/collect method on an array to modify it:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.collect! {|x| x + "!" }
a                            #=>  [ "a!", "b!", "c!", "d!" ]
```

Is there a simple way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
a = a.Select( s => s + "!" ).ToArray();
```

Comment: be aware that this creates a new array and does not modify original array, as asked in OP's question.

Comment: @spender: Very true. 'a =' in the beginning only takes care of making this particular reference point to the new array, if there's other references to the original array, they won't be updated.

Comment: @spender & tanzelax: Yes, I understand that. Creating a new array was exactly what I wanted anyways, in ruby you can call the map/collect method without an exclamation point at the end to create a new array and not modify the one you called the method on.

Comment: If working with Web application, creating a global object and change the object, the object will always be updated when asigning the new lambda created array to the variable. Also create a Viewstate variable, Always helps with page refeshes... 
private List<string> myArray{ get { return (ViewState["myArray"] != null) ? (List<string>)ViewState["myArray"] : null; } set { ViewState["myArray"] = value; } }

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using ConvertAll since it's quicker and I believe more intuitive.

```
var a = a.ConvertAll(x => x + "!").ToArray();
```

Since I prefer the naming, I personally use my own [Enumerable Map Extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/573f2d5bff241ff78293ffc52feb3557c1a47fba/src/ServiceStack.Common/EnumerableExtensions.cs#L175-L201) which is available to all `IEnumerable<T>` Types, guards against `null` and follows the standing naming in other languages for functinoal projection.

```
var to = a.Map(x => x + "!");
```

Comment: What makes this quicker or more intuitive?

Comment: It's quicker because you don't have to create an lazy-loaded enumerable in the interim. IMO it's more readable because it says exactly what it does. Map is what most other langs use.

Comment: So then wouldn't `Map` be more intuitive?

Comment: `ConvertAll` is built-into LINQ whereas `Map` doesn't exist in .NET.

Comment: BTW you don't need import Linq to use ConvertAll

Comment: @mythz are you sure `ConvertAll` is LINQ when you don't have to import it? As a starting C# developer, I would think this is just coming from `System.collections.generic` and the `List` class in that namespace.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Right it's just an API on `List<T>` instead of a LINQ extension method, the difference doesn't mean too much in practice (just lacks the import of System.Linq as you've observed). I use my own [Map Enumearable extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/573f2d5bff241ff78293ffc52feb3557c1a47fba/src/ServiceStack.Common/EnumerableExtensions.cs#L175-L201) since I prefer using standard functional naming over what .NET BCL uses + works over all `IEnumerable<T>` types. The reason to use Select() vs Map() is if you want eager vs lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
var a = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

a = a.Select(p => p + "!").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, using Linq (but this won't modify the original collection)

```
var a=new[]{"a","b","c","d"};
a.Select(x=>x+"!");
```